# Where to find Eclipse Mars syntax coloring preferences file?

Tags: eclipse

I've just installed Eclipse Oxygen (on Ubuntu) after using Eclipse Mars. I'd really like to get my hands on the preferences file that stored the custom java syntax coloring that I had set. I've been searching through files in the `.metadata` directory of my old workspace, but I can't find anything. I was using the Moonrise UI theme, in case that's relevant.

I know I might not be able to re-use the old prefs file directly, but at least I'll have the colors available (presumably hex values).

I've found a prefs file at:

> myworkspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings/org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.ui.prefs

...which I thought was the correct file. I tried importing it using the eclipse wizard and by overwriting my Oxygen file of the same name with the Mars file (and restarting eclipse). Neither had any effect. The java syntax coloring is the same default coloring that my theme provided. Maybe that's the problem? I'm using the Darkest Dark UI theme. Does that store coloring prefs somewhere else?

Comment: You can **Export** and **Import** most of your preferences from the **File** menu.

Comment: Hopefully that will be useful, but I still need to know where the preferences file is though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The preference file you mention is for the Javascript development tools (JSDT).

The main Java development tools (JDT) UI preferences are in the `org.eclipse.jdt.ui.prefs` file in the same directory.

**But** this contains all the Java UI preferences, you will overwrite everything changing this. Also there is no guarantee that preference files from different releases are compatible.

Comment: That's great, thanks. I'll cherry pick the `java_[type]=R,G,B` lines from the Mars file and put them into the Oxygen file.

Comment: Actually, this isn't as simple as I thought. When I change the RGB color value for an entry in the prefs file (e.g. `java_keyword_return`) and I restart Eclipse, my new value is replaced with the original default value. Is it because of the UI theme I'm using? Where are these values coming from?

Comment: I don't know, the source code for all this is extremely complicated.  Some preference need to have an 'enabled' preference as well.